# Join on Date Ranges

Tags: mysql, date, join, range, date-range

I've looked at other answers to this question but haven't found a solution.

I have two tables with a tracking number, one has status history and several records per tracking with different date times for each status. The other table is a cost table that has one record per tracking with a date time that is in the same general time period of the status table but never exact.

I cannot join just on the tracking number itself due to the duplication of the tracking number in the data from months prior. Ex. a tracking number may appear in March of 2019 and again in January of 2020 even though they are very different parcels being shipped. However if you concatenate the tracking with the orderid on the status table you do get a unique value. That orderid number though is not in the cost table so you cannot join the two tables on that value either. It has to be tracking and a date range of some sort.

So I am looking to join the two tables using the tracking number and a date range of +- 30 days from the date provided on the cost table and the final date for that tracking number on the status table.

So something like this without the "is in a 30 day window" part clearly.

```
SELECT C.cost
     , S.trackingnumber
  From UPSCost C
  join UPSStatus S
    ON C.trackingnumber = S.trackingnumber
 WHERE MAX(S.date_time) is in a 30 day window of C.event_date_time
```

Comment: Please provide sampe data and expected results.

Comment: Please provide more details on what you see and what is expected.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You could expand your `join` and add the date condition to it. Something like this.

```
SELECT      
    C.cost,     
    S.trackingnumber 
From UPSCost C
    join UPSStatus S
    ON(
        -- Same tracking number
        C.trackingnumber = S.trackingnumber AND
        -- status updated within -+30 days from the date found in cost table
        s.date_time between DATE_SUB(C.event_date_time, interval 30 day) AND DATE_ADD(C.event_date_time, interval 30 day)
    )
Order by S.date_time desc -- latest status first?
```